# banning nodes through bitcoin-cli in Windows

Tags: bitcoin-cli, windows

I'd like to use Greg Maxwell's banlist for my Bitcoin node in Windows.

When I enter the commands however, I receive the following error message for every bitcoin-cli command:

> bitcoin\bin>bitcoin-cli setban ###.###.###.###/32 add 31557600 error:
>   Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be
>   found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and
>   -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf)

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bitcoin-cli could not locate RPC credentials](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/bitcoin-cli-could-not-locate-rpc-credentials)

Comment: What's in your bitcoin.conf file? Did you change the data directory used by Bitcoin Core either via the -datadir option or in the GUI the first time you started it?

Comment: Actually the command worked now when referring to the correct bitcoin.conf file and data directory as parameters (thank you!) - however, the "setban" parameter throws a "Method not found" error message.

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core are you using?

Comment: version 0.17.0.1